# Getting column description from datatable schema

Tags: c#, schema, database-connection

I want to know details of columns. I learnt it from Microsoft's site. But still I don't know how to get column's description. Below I got the code block from Microsoft Support site.

```
OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection();
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
DataTable schemaTable; 
OleDbDataReader myReader; 

cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=server;User ID=login;
                       Password=password;Initial Catalog=Northwind";
cn.Open();
cmd.Connection = cn;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Employees";
myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo); 
schemaTable = myReader.GetSchemaTable();
foreach (DataRow myField in schemaTable.Rows){
    foreach (DataColumn myProperty in schemaTable.Columns) {
    Console.WriteLine(myProperty.ColumnName + " = " + myField[myProperty].ToString());
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
myReader.Close();
cn.Close();
```

Please, could you help me, in this code block, how do I get the column's description?

Comment: Why do you want a description in combination with the rows in the table?, do you want to know the type of a column? If you would request the description of the table with each result you are wasting resources/memory.

Comment: @Mike de Klerk - When i get the column.DataType, nvarchar, varchar, text, etc. are coming as System.String. Yes they are string but which type. So i thought, if i get description, i know which is which. is it wrong that i think?

Comment: No its not wrong, but I could not think of a reason why you wish to know the difference between a text / varchar datatype in the database. In C# this all translates to a string or array of chars anyway.

Comment: Because next stage, i want to get all database with their structure as an sql file. I know, there are some methods about this idea. But when i analysed them, i was confused. :)